# Links for triggering a certain <div> to slide up and a link for triggering the <div> to slide down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to make some (let's say 2) links that will trigger a specific  to appear by sliding up , then another link that will trigger the specific  to huide by sliding down.

The links are generated dynamically by a certain application (something like looping which I personally don't understand)

After researching in this site, I tried the code below but found some problems:

1. only the first link for sliding up worked well, other blue links didn't work
2. Current script is sliding up and down the content for each click on the blue link. 
   I can't figure out how to break apart the script so I can apply sliding up script only for the blue links and the sliding down script for the red link.
3. to be noted, the blue links are dynamically generated based on a certain application loop, so practically there is no fix number for the amount of the blue links being displayed.

This is the code :

```js
   $(function(){
    var list = $('#slidingcontent'),
        button = $('#triggerup'),
        speed = 500;
    
    list.hide().css('bottom', button.css('top'))
        .css('margin-top', list.outerHeight() * -1);
                    
    button.toggle(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        list.slideDown(speed);
    },function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        list.slideUp(speed);
    });
});
```

```css
#slidingcontent{
    position:absolute;
}
.linkcontainer{
    text-align:center;
}
.sliding_up_link a, .sliding_down_link a, #slidingcontent{
    color:white;
    margin: 1px;
    padding: 1px; 
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.sliding_up_link a{
    background:blue;
}
.sliding_down_link a{
    background:red;
}
#slidingcontent{
    background:green;
}
```

```html
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    
  
    
    
    <div class= "linkcontainer">

    <span class="sliding_up_link" id="triggerup" >
        <a href ="#">
            triggerup1 (for sliding upward)</br>
                        the amount of links(for triggering content to slide up) is uncertain based on conditions (it maybe only 1 link, or 3 links like this, or 7 links, or 15 links, etc)
        </a>
    </span>

</div>   


    <div class= "linkcontainer">

    <span class="sliding_up_link" id="triggerup" >
        <a href ="#">
            triggerup2 (for sliding upward)</br>
            the amount of links(for triggering content to slide up) is uncertain based on conditions (it maybe only 1 link, or 3 links like this, or 7 links, or 15 links, etc)
        </a>
    </span>

</div>   

<div class= "linkcontainer">

    <span class="sliding_down_link" id="triggerdown" >
        <a href ="#">
            triggerdown (for sliding down)</br>
            only one link (for triggering content to slide down) will be displayed 
        </a>
    </span>

</div>  

<div id="slidingcontent">
content here
</div>
</body>
```

Thanks for help :)

Comment: IDs must be unique on document context, use class instead and any transversal method to target the specific one

Comment: thanks, it works ! It solves my #1 & #3 problems ! Then, how should I edit my script function so that slide up and slide down function can be separated to 2 different functions ? BTW, sorry if my question is unclear, this is my first question around here :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me. I corrected the HTML validation errors in your code as well.

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#slidingcontent").css({"display": "none", "opacity": "1"});
    });
        
    $(window).load(function () {
        var speed = 500,
            target = $("#slidingcontent");
        $(".sliding_up").on("click", function () {
            target.slideDown(speed);
        });
        $(".sliding_down").on("click", function () {
            target.slideUp(speed);
        });
    });
});
```

```css
#slidingcontent {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: -2px;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 0!important;
}
.linkcontainer {
    text-align:center;
}
p.sliding_up, p.sliding_down, #slidingcontent {
    color:white;
    margin: 1px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
}
p.sliding_up, p.sliding_down {
    cursor: pointer;
    display:inline-block;
}
p.sliding_up {
    background:blue;
}
p.sliding_down {
    background:red;
}
#slidingcontent {
    background:green;
}
.wrap {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="linkcontainer">
        <p class="sliding_up">trigger up 1 (for sliding upward)</p>
    </div>
    <div class="linkcontainer">
        <p class="sliding_up">trigger up 2 (for sliding upward)</p>
    </div>
    <div class="linkcontainer">
        <p class="sliding_down">triggerdown (for sliding down)</p>
    </div>
    <div id="slidingcontent">content here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I clicked the links on your snippet without any effect. I think the jquery does not work ?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to add the jquery library to the snippet. It should work fine now, ;-)

Comment: I would use the JSFiddle version, because for the SO one, I had to add a very unelegant `bottom: -2px;` that shouldn't be necessary at all.

Comment: The non-JSFiddle version works very well on IE8 too, but for an unknown reason doesn't work (on IE8) after being implemented on my site, something must be wrong with my site, should try it again soon LOL. Anyway thanks ! :D

Comment: Strange. If you can't figure it out on your site, paste a link and I'll take a look.

Comment: I'd like to, but it's still not a live site LOL. Ok, will contact you if I can't figure it out.thx 4 kindness :)